# Nested weights are bad for performance

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's my layout, I'm getting this message for the 2 buttons in the bottom, even though I have set the weight only for one other widget in the layout, which is not the parent of the buttons (the messageText widget). What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView  
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/status_label"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textColor="#FEFF80"/>
    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/statusText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/unsent"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textColor="#FEFF80"/>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#FEFF80"/>
<TextView  
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/message_number_caption"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/messageNumber"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView  
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/message_text_caption"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
<EditText android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/messageText"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dip"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" 
        android:text="@string/send_button_label"
        android:textSize="15dip"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_width="0dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/reset_button_label"
        android:textSize="15dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified an edit text (@+id/messageText) with a weight of 1 - did you mean to do that because the other widgets in that linear layout don't have a weight?

Then below that you have a linearlayout with two buttons that use weight legitimately.

N.B. it's quite a simple layout so you're probably fine. If you had deeper hierarchy with more layouts and widgets then you would be more likely to see a slow down.

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing anything wrong, its just a warning. The Android view engine interprets your XML and builds view objects. Google had decided that having nested weights (that is, a view with a `android:layout_weight` attribute) inside a layout, inside another layout causes the view engine to perform poorly and they advise that you don't do it.

If there is another way to achieve the layout you're building without using the `andorid:layout_weight` attribute, it would be best to do it that way. Otherwise, your view may load a little slowly.